# Mysql exclude a subset from a set

Tags: mysql

It's a while that I'm trying to sort this out, but to no avail!

**The problem**
Consider a set where there are a few subsets (i.e. 3 subsets) presented below:
[image: Collection with 3 subsets]

**The Question**
Is there anyway that I can SELECT the COLLECTION **excluding** SUB3?

I have tried many things, such as: `LEFT JOIN`, `JOIN`, `NOT IN`, `NOT EXISTS`, and further more multiple `SELECT` sub queries.

```
SELECT 
    t1.*, t2.*
FROM
    table AS t1
        LEFT JOIN
    table AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE
    t1.attribute = 'COLLECTION'
        AND t2.attribute = 'SUB3'
        AND oa2.id IS NULL;
```

**Note**
Please note that the `table` holds about 75 million entries (rows) and I'm looking to have something fast!

**Update**
**Example**

```
+-----+-------------+
| id  | attribute   |
+-----+-------------+
|  1  | vehicle     |
|  1  | bus         |
|  2  | vehicle     |
|  2  | car         |
|  3  | vehicle     |
|  3  | truck       |
+-----+-------------+  
Of course there is a second incremental id to avoid duplicate issues!
```

Thus in this example, I would want all the vehicles except the `truck`s!

Please advise,
Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all the element that you don't need with a NOT EXISTS

```
SELECT *
FROM table t
WHERE t.attribute = 'COLLECTION'
AND NOT EXISTS (    SELECT 'a'
                    FROM table t2
                    WHERE t2.id = t.id
                    AND t2.attribule = 'SUB3'
                )
```

Comment: Thanks, surprisingly it does work as it should, but the only draw back is performance. I get like ~ 200 secs query time! If in any chance you found anything faster, I would appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the `id`s that do not have `attribute = 'SUB3'`, then you can approach this using `group by` and `having`:

```
select t.id
from table t
where t.attribute = 'COLLECTION'
group by t.id
having sum(t.attribute = 'COLLECTION' AND t.attribute = 'SUB3') = 0
```

The `where` clause is optional, but it may improve performance.

Comment: Could you explain your query please? I still do have values from SUB3 and there is a thing that I don't understand is why SUM? My values aren't numerical at all!

Comment: One other thing is `SELECT SUM(attribute = 'COLLECTION' AND attribute = 'SUB3') from table;` is always `0` !

Comment: @Hamed . . . Then those two values never appear together on the same row.

Comment: did you take a look at my example?